# Combining two observeable collection to a listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have two observeable collection both set to a class of properties. I am needing to combine both of those collections into one listbox. I have looked up at the Compositecollection class but it is not what I need. Ideally, I want the listbox to look like this...

Think of this as a listbox control and each listbox item contains objects from the source properties of two observeable collection.

```
Collection1 Collection1
--------------------------
Data          Data
--------------------------
Data          Data
--------------------------
Data          Data
--------------------------
Data          Data
--------------------------
Data          Data
--------------------------
```

I am just wondering if it will actually be possible to do something like that?

Comment: What would be the DisplayMember and ValueMember of this ListBox ?

Comment: Maybe you could give a more concrete example? How are items in your first and second list related?

Answer (score 1):

Well if I got your question right,

you can create a another collection (say a List) where each element would be an anonymous type (or a type depends on what you want as a DisplayMember and ValueMember) composed of each element of Collection1 and Collection2.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then no. ListBox can only bind to one source. What you could do is combine both collection into one, then use a multibinding to show both sets of data on each line.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you should be able to do that by using a Linq Join

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultiBinding and define a converter that will join the two (or more) collections into one.

Answer (score 0):

CompositeCollection/CollectionContainer - they are your friend